Passing image path from mdx file to Picture component in Astro.js
I'm writing a web in Astro.js.
My folder structure is like this:
src
 |-assets
 | |-images
 |   |-blog
 |     |-image1.jpg
 |-components
 | |-BlogPost.astro
 |-content
 | |-blog
 | | |-my-first-blogpost.mdx
 | |-config.js

I have a relative path to image src/assets/images/blog/image1.jpg in my mdx file:
---
title: "My First Blogpost"
image: "../../assets/images/blog/image1.jpg"
---
...

In my config.js I have defined the collection:
import { docsSchema } from '@astrojs/starlight/schema';
import { defineCollection, z } from 'astro:content';

const posts = defineCollection({
  type: 'content',
  schema: ({ image }) =>
    z.object({
      title: z.string(),
      image: image(),
      imageAlt: z.string()
    }),
});

const docs = defineCollection({ schema: docsSchema() });

export const collections = {
  posts
};

And my Astro component looks like this:
---
import type { CollectionEntry } from 'astro:content';
import { Picture } from 'astro:assets';

interface Props {
  post: CollectionEntry<'posts'>;
}

const { post } = Astro.props;
---

<div>
  <Picture
      src={post.data.image}
      alt={post.data.imageAlt}
      class='aspect-[727/410] w-full object-cover object-left md:hidden'
      formats={['webp', 'avif']}
      densities={[1, 2, 3]}
    />
</div>

But I'm getting:
LocalImageUsedWrongly
Local images must be imported.

But I thought that it is imported in that config.js file via defining that type. Do I have to register the posts collection exported from config.js somewhere?
Thanks
